# vuejs nginx subdirectory deployment on refresh 404

Tags: vue.js, nginx

i have configure my nginx with these config

```
  location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
  }

  location /apps/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ index.php;
  }
```

my result of `npm run build` i was rename `mv dist apps`

the first router path `'/'` would redirect to `/login` path

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  scrollBehavior() {
    return { x: 0, y: 0 }
  },
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'auth-login',
      component: () => import('@/views/pages/authentication/Login.vue'),
      meta: {
        layout: 'full',
        resource: 'Auth',
        redirectIfLoggedIn: true,
      },
    },
  ]
```

so when i going to `www.subdomain.maindomain.id/apps` would like redirect into `www.subdomain.maindomain.id/apps/login`

but when i tried refresh , 404 is appear. ( File not found. )

i have was tried with other

```
location = /apps/ {
#   try_files $uri $uri/ /apps/dist/index.html;
#   alias /apps/dist/index.html;
  return 301 /apps/dist/index.php;
}

location /apps/dist/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ index.php;
}
location @rewrites {
        rewrite ^.*$ /index.html last;
}
```

still i got 404 on refresh

and this my full config nginx https://gist.github.com/yogithesymbian/b137be9aa2adb87ac7652b9bfbf9394c

if i change my mode to hash

```
mode: 'hash',
```

my page can be refresh but have `#`

Answer (score 0):

I think u need a redirect for '/apps/login' to '/apps' in nginx.

For Vue, there is one page only, which is the root page (rest pages are generated by js). Although you see /apps/login, /apps/login.html or /apps/login.php do not actually exist. In other words, file /apps/dist/login.php(in your case, nginx run:try_files $uri $uri/ index.php; ) is not found. Therefore, it return 404.

Personally, I do not recommend to use history. It is too clumsy for building up the redirect path for these similar case. If you don't want to handle that, use hash mode and utilize routes function in Vue.